# OpenGL ES in Eclipse with MinGW for Windows

Tags: eclipse, opengl-es, mingw

I want to compile OpenGL ES programs in Eclipse for use in an emulator like that of PowerVR's. I have Eclipse setup with MinGW and can make a basic C++ hello-world executable, so this is a good start. I have found these OpenGL ES [examples](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/wiki/Instructions) and want to be able to build them in Eclipse, so I guess the next step is getting Eclipse to build an OpenGL ES application. The examples want me to use Visual Studio, but I am not interested in using that. My main target is Desktop and Android so sticking to Eclipse would prove beneficial I'd think. I see there are many libraries like GLEW that greatly help with making OpenGL graphic applications, but these I'm guessing cannot be compiled for OpenGL ES for a mobile platform-- unless that's a bad assumption. I am coming from a background of having once used OpenGL with glut to make OpenGL applications. I guess I am confused on how to proceed in order to start programming something that is both ready for desktop and mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading the ARM MALI [emulator](http://www.malideveloper.com/opengl-es-20-emulator.php) for OpenGL ES, and after some configuration to get it to build in Eclipse, I think I am on my way now. It builds rather easily, and with the included dll files I can get it to run under Windows; so now I can begin programming for OpenGL ES and be sure it will likely work on a mobile platform that supports OpenGL ES-- I don't have an Android device, nor a mac computer so this seems ideal for now. I suppose eventually I will install GLEW and GLUT when I decide to program for the desktop and have a better understanding of what is available in OpenGL ES 2.0 that is also available for the standard OpenGL.